# Related ICollection entity cannot be null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

My model has this field:

```
public ICollection<Guest> SecondaryGuests { get; set; }
```

and it also has this `get` to count results:

```
public int TotalRSVP
{
     get
     {
         return (GuestOf == null && 
             SecondaryGuests.Any() ? RSVP + SecondaryGuests.Count() : 0);
     }
 }
```

This is working great EXCEPT when I use the `Create` and `Edit` methods, throws an exception:

> SecondaryGuests cannot be null

I was able to get around this on the `Edit` method by adding an `include`:

```
var guestToUpdate = await _context.Guests
    .Include(g => g.SecondaryGuests)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(g => g.ID == id);
```

However on the `Create` method I am not sure what to do to get around this.

I could put the `get` field in a `ViewModel`, but this creates a ton of extra work on my index and details view etc. I would rather modify my `Create` method or figure out how to ignore the `get` on the `Create` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Any()` (which will give that error when `SecondaryGuests` is `null`), simply check for `null` and the `Count()`:

```
return (GuestOf == null && SecondaryGuests != null && SecondaryGuests.Count() > 0 ?
        RSVP + SecondaryGuests.Count() : 0);
```

Comment: Oops!  Was over-complicating this one big time trying all kinds of things except the most basic.